# Google Maps API - I need only one waypoint

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I get the value of ONLY ONE WAYPOINT from a text box and I try to draw a route from start to end through this waypoint but it doesn't work.

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var waypts = document.getElementById('way').value;

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts
    };
```

Comment: By "it doesn't work", what do you mean?  Do you get errors, are the results unexpected, ...?

Comment: I do not know what is other code but from what is available at least one is wrong: `waypoints` has to be an array. Try with `var waypts = [document.getElementById('way').value];`

Comment: Anto, i tried your version but i still get nothing.

Comment: It doesn't work meaning that no route is drawn on the map, no errors

Comment: Point is to read that value and build and array from it for `var waypts`. Check your code and example from google docs [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints). It is hard to say what is wrong without other code.

Comment: this the link where the whole code is copied (i only omitted the link for generating maps): http://pastebin.com/XfzefHR7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation on waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

waypts needs to be an array of [DirectionsWaypoint objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint)

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var waypts = document.getElementById('way').value;

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: [{location:waypts, stopover: true}]
  };
```

[example with single waypoint](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsD.html)